# Why image not fit to table cell height in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to split screen to two area left and right,in right segment show a image and in right segment show textbox,for that purpose write this html code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="width:50%;height:100%;" align="center">
                <img src="../Content/45.png" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:50%;">
                behzad
            </td>

          </tr>

        </table>
```

but when i run the html page ,image not fit to the table column height,and i must scroll the browser to see all of the page,i want just fit to the screen height,my out put i this :
[image]

Comment: You must fix the height of table without % or fix the height of the container out of the table.With your code you use 100% respect of alla page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport units `vh/vw`, and to keep aspect ratio on the image, set the style on the image to `display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100vw">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50vw;height:100vh;" align="center">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals" style="display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:50vh;">
      behzad
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in my page need to scroll

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

in this case you'd better use background-image instead of `<img>` to avoid stretching

check the following demo

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
table{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="width:50%;height:100%;background-image:url(http://placehold.it/600x600)" align="center">
      
            </td>
            <td style="width:50%;">
                behzad
            </td>

          </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: you gave the image both with and height `100%` which make the result as it appear you have to adjust the height regardless of the width

Answer (score 0):

> emphasized text

instead of this section
`<img src="../Content/45.png" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%;" />`

try this section
`<img src="../Content/45.png" height="50%" />`

I hope it works